# iOS: Call delegate method in view to make that view modal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a TabBar messaging application with two views, A and B. In view A, I declared an object of type delegate which has a delegate method in view B. Now, whenever something happens in view A, the method in the delegate object gets called, which then triggers the delegate method in view B to fire. What I want to happen whenever this "something" happens is that if it's view A that is visible, I want the tab bar to switch the view to view B. If view B is visible, nothing happens to the view. How do I make this happen?

The actual app is more complicated than the one described above because the TabBar and all its associated views are in another view controller that gets loaded in the appdelegate. (I am a contributor to this app and the original developers in their infinite wisdom decided to make things really cryptic.) And I don't want to implement the solution that uses something along the lines of ...

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]
```

... because that is not how I want it to happen. I just want to make the view in B visible whenever delegate in view A is called. Thanks.

I had edited my post: This line [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1] and the clauses above and underneath it make up one line. I put ellipsis points to emphasize.

Comment: > "that is not how I want it to happen." Now, **that** is "cryptic".

Comment: In your edit, there is just this one line of code, no "clauses above and underneath". Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to determine which view is visible you can use the `-isDesendentOfView:` method:

```
  if([viewA isDescendentOfView:someView]) {
      //viewA is visible as a subview to `someView`
 }
```

**EDIT:** Upon reading your question over. I think you want to send the `sender` parameter in to your delegate method to determine where it came from..i,e:

If your delegate method was defined as this:

```
-(void)someMethod:(id)sender;
```

In your delegate you would do something like this:

```
-(void)someMethod:(id)sender {

    UIView *aView = (UIView*)sender;

        if(aView == viewA) {

       }

        if(aView == viewB) {

       }
}
```

Hope this helps, or at least put's you on the path to figuring it out !

Comment: Actually, view B does not have to check where the call came from because the delegate method that will be fired in this particular view was triggered by the view that has the delegate object which is view A. Your second suggestion makes sense, I'm gonna use it to check whether view B is visible or not. Is there a method somewhere that tells a hidden view (say, view B) to make itself visible? Note that these views are already loaded in memory, and the method (in view B) just has to make view B visible.

Comment: View's have a `setHidden:` method, and a `isHidden` property. Assuming you're using `[viewB setHidden:YES]` you can do `[viewB isHidden]` which will return `TRUE`.

Comment: I tried setHidden and isHidden as you have suggested but my view becomes white and empty. I ended up using '[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.contactsViewController animated:YES]' to push a new view in place. This solution isn't perfect as it creates a totally new instance of the view (which I do not want; memory issues, too) but it gets the job done. No alternative solution is sight, yet. I'll have your suggestion (which is quite helpful, btw) upvoted for your help.

Comment: Alright, sorry about that but my reputation apparently is not enough for me to upvote. :-(